# .htaccess redirect for old subfolder installation to new subfolder installation and https

Tags: redirect, htaccess

Our old WP website: https://www.domainname.com/oldsite/
Our new WP website: https://www.domainname.com/newsite/

We want to make sure that no matter what page they land on, on the old site, will redirect them to the HOME PAGE of the NEW site.  Notice both sites are installed in sub-folders of the main domain name and the whole domain name has a secure certificate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably should have been asked on stackoverflow as its not wordpress specific. However, what youre looking for is a wildcard.

You can find information about using them to do what you need here [htaccess wildcards](http://alvinalexander.com/web/apache-redirectmatch-examples-wildcard-301)